# ClientProtocolException on executing HttpGet with apache DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android, apache, authorization, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using apache DefaultHttpClient

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(Constants.GET_ADDRESS_2_LETTERS_URL + params[0]);

            StringEntity se;
            httpGetRequest.addHeader("Authorization", SharedPrefsSingleton.getInstance().getSharedPrefs().getString(Constants.USER_AUTHORIZATION, null));
            httpGetRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpGetRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpGetRequest);
```

Sometimes I get the `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException` on the `HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpGetRequest);` line

My `Authorization` header :

```
public String getBase64(String str)
{
    return Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

everything else is quite common. The problem occurs sometimes, not usual.

What can be the cause of this ?

Comment: `My Authorization header :` getBase64 ?

Comment: greenapps, yes, I save it to the SharedPreferences and put as a header